# Logistic growth in R and TI 84 gave different results

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
x <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)
y <- c(110,235,435,655,830,930,980)
population <- data.frame(y,x)
```

When I try to compute the parameters of a logistic growth model:

```
fit_data <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, phi1, phi2, phi3), data = population)
alpha <- coef(fit_data)  #extracting coefficients
```

I obtain the following coefficients:

```
    phi1 
1015.103 
    phi2 
33.29877 
    phi3 
11.11867
```

Which are very different from those obtained using a TI-84 calculator: `1015.1, 19.98, -0.09`. Anyone can explain this difference? Am I doing something wrong with R?

Comment: What exactly are you running on your calculator? The two methods probably parameterize the problem differently.

Comment: If you plot the R results, the fit looks excellent, so nothing is wrong in R. It's possible you're doing something wrong on your calculator, or as MrFlick says it's possible it's a different parameterization, i.e., a different way to write the same result.

Comment: I am following the example in `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9iBVnLJB0Y` which try to model a set of data using and exponential regression and/or a logistic regression.

Comment: Yes, I think R and TI 84 use different expressions: in R `c/(1 + exp(-(x - a)/b))` and in TI 84 
`c/(1 + a * exp(-b * x))`.